# Is it possible that in a water soluble polamerization, by injecting some additional initiator, the monomer concentration increases?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, polymers

I have a simple polymerization process with the following kinetic mechanism:

$$I_2 \stackrel{k_d}{\rightarrow}2\dot{I}$$
$$\dot{I}+M\stackrel{k_p}{\rightarrow}\dot{P_1}$$
$$\dot{P}_i + M\stackrel{k_p}{\rightarrow}~~\dot{P}_{i+1}$$
$$\dot{P}_i + \dot{P}_j\stackrel{\frac{1}{2}k_{tc}}{\rightarrow} D_{i+j}$$

This polymerization is taking place in a tubular reactor.

By default, the initiator is injected at the inlet of the reactor. Now, in addition to this injection, I have added another injection of the initiator at the middle of the reactor. I am expecting that the monomer concentration at the reactor outlet reduces, but this does not happen. Indeed, the monomer concentration at the reactor outlet increases.

I wanted to ask you guys, if such a behaviour is possible?